# Local Surjectivity of Continuously differentiable maps

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $V$, $W$ are banach spaces, $\alpha \in V$ and $f$ maps from an open set $U$ containing $\alpha$ to $W$.

Suppose further $f$ is continuously differentiable in $U$ (in a frechet manner), and that $df$ is a surjective map in $Hom(V,W)$, is it true that $f(U)$ is a neighborhood of $f(\alpha)$?

A claim similar to this appeared in the book Advanced Calculus by Loomis and Sternberg, where it is suggested that it follows naturally from the implicit-function theorem. However, I am having some difficulty proving this.

Comment: To apply the implicit function theorem wouldn't one need that $df$ is not only surjective but has a continuous linear right inverse (equivalently, the kernel of $df$ is complemented)? However, a proof is contained in Jean Claude Tougeron, *Ideaux de fonctions differentiables*, chapitre III.6. There must be references which are better accessible.

Comment: Ok, so if the kernel has a closed complement, this fact follows from the inverse/implicit function theorem right? But the general case is true but harder?

Comment: I just read about the constant rank theorem, this seems like a consequence.